# Return Hierarchical data from MySQL tables using ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby, json, activerecord, hierarchy

In the Database (mySQL), I have a table named `tests` and a related (via FK) table called `cars`. Using the `ActiveRecord` gem, I added the classes for these tables in `schema.rb`:

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars
end

class Car <ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tests
end
```

Running the simple script below:

```
puts "the Test Object identified by name 'Rob'"
puts Test.find_by_name("Rob").to_json
puts "Cool - no problem!"
puts ""
puts "the cars that belong to Rob 
puts Test.find_by_name("Rob").cars.to_json
puts "Correct - Rob has 2 cars "
```

produces the expected result:

```
the Test Object identified by name 'Rob'
{"test":{"idtest":1,"name":"Rob","rugby_team":"Lions"}}
Cool - no problem!

the cars that belong to Rob 
[
    {"car":{"car_make":"Honda","idcars":1,"test_id":1}},
    {"car":{"car_make":"Nissan","idcars":7,"test_id":1}}
]
Correct - Rob has 2 cars!
```

I imagined that the second query should have returned json that looked like this (an array of `Car` objects):

```
{cars: [ 
    {"car_make":"Honda","idcars":1,"test_id":1},
    {"car_make":"Nissan","idcars":7,"test_id":1}
    ]}
```

**Question 1 :** What am I doing wrong in the above example?

**Question 2 :** What must I change to get the cars belonging to Rob as part of the first Test Object? (as the below example)

What I need to be returned:

```
{"test":{"idtest":1,"name":"Rob","rugby_team":"Lions", 
    {cars: [ 
        {"car_make":"Honda","idcars":1,"test_id":1},
        {"car_make":"Nissan","idcars":7,"test_id":1}
        ]}
     }
}
```